# Trouble with digraphs: cannot borrow as mutable

Tags: rust, compiler-errors, linked-list, digraphs

I created a [library](https://github.com/vporton/simple-digraph-rs/blob/ae5f49507bb0b4c6198ae66bb4aad0a3fd9700dc/src/lib.rs) to deal with digraphs: nodes that link (reference counted) to zero or one other nodes (as in linked lists, but in a digraph a node can be linked to by more than one node).

I am trying to use my library to create a list with a current node:

```rust
struct ListWithPointer<'a> {
    pub nodes: DigraphNodeRef<String>,
    pub current_node: Option<&'a mut DigraphNodeRef<String>>,
}
```

`current_node` points to a link in the list.

Now I am trying to move current node to the next element of the list (or to the beginning if the list ended):

```rust
fn next_node<'a>(this: &'a mut ListWithPointer<'a>) {
    if this.current_node.is_some() {
        this.current_node.iter_mut().for_each(|a| {
            (*a).as_rc_mut().iter_mut()
                .for_each(|rc| this.current_node = Some(&mut Arc::get_mut(rc).unwrap().next));
        });
    } else {
        this.current_node = Some(&mut this.nodes);
    }
}
```

but whatever I do, it fails with an error like:

```
error[E0500]: closure requires unique access to `this.current_node` but it is already borrowed
   --> src/lib.rs:150:51
    |
148 |     fn next_node<'a>(this: &'a mut ListWithPointer<'a>) {
    |                  -- lifetime `'a` defined here
149 |         if this.current_node.is_some() {
150 |             this.current_node.iter_mut().for_each(|a| {
    |             ----------------------------          ^^^ closure construction occurs here
    |             |
    |             borrow occurs here
    |             argument requires that `this.current_node` is borrowed for `'a`
151 |                 (*a).as_rc_mut().iter_mut()
152 |                     .for_each(|rc| this.current_node = Some(&mut Arc::get_mut(rc).unwrap().next));
    |                                    ----------------- second borrow occurs due to use of `this.current_node` in closure
```

Help to rewrite without errors.

Here is the library code:

```rust
use std::sync::Arc;

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct DigraphNode<T> {
    pub next: DigraphNodeRef<T>, // I made it `pub` to be able `item.next.next()` to remove an item from the middle.
    data: T,
}

impl<T> DigraphNode<T> {
    fn new(next: DigraphNodeRef<T>, data: T) -> Self {
        Self { next, data }
    }
}

pub struct DigraphNodeRef<T> {
    rc: Option<Arc<DigraphNode<T>>>,
}

impl<T> DigraphNodeRef<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            rc: None
        }
    }
    pub fn from_node(value: DigraphNode<T>) -> Self {
        Self::from(Some(Arc::new(value)))
    }
    pub fn from(rc: Option<Arc<DigraphNode<T>>>) -> Self {
        Self {
            rc
        }
    }
    pub fn as_rc(&self) -> &Option<Arc<DigraphNode<T>>> {
        &self.rc
    }
    pub fn as_rc_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Option<Arc<DigraphNode<T>>> {
        &mut self.rc
    }
    pub fn is_none(&self) -> bool {
        self.rc.is_none()
    }
    pub fn remove(&mut self) -> bool {
        if let Some(rc) = self.rc.clone() {
            self.rc = rc.next.rc.clone();
            true
        } else {
            false
        }
    }
    pub fn prepend(&mut self, value: T) -> Self {
        let new_node = DigraphNode::new(self.clone(), value);
        let new_node_ref = DigraphNodeRef::from_node(new_node);
        *self = new_node_ref.clone();
        new_node_ref
    }
    pub fn node(&self) -> Option<DigraphNode<T>>
        where T: Clone
    {
        self.rc.clone().map(|node| (*node).clone())
    }
    /// TODO: Should return a reference.
    pub fn data(&self) -> Option<T>
        where T: Clone
    {
        self.rc.clone().map(|node| (*node).data.clone())
    }
    pub fn values(self) -> DigraphNodeValuesIterator<T> {
        DigraphNodeValuesIterator {
            underlying: self.clone()
        }
    }
}

impl<T> Clone for DigraphNodeRef<T> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        Self { rc: self.rc.clone() }
    }
}

impl<T> Iterator for DigraphNodeRef<T> {
    type Item = Arc<DigraphNode<T>>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if let Some(rc) = self.rc.clone() {
            self.rc = rc.next.rc.clone();
            Some(rc.clone())
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

pub struct DigraphNodeValuesIterator<T> {
    underlying: DigraphNodeRef<T>,
}

impl<T: Clone> Iterator for DigraphNodeValuesIterator<T> {
    type Item = T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.underlying.next().map(|node| node.data.clone())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Rust the mutable access is ensured to be exclusive, i.e. if you hold a reference, some other code can't grab a mutable reference.

Problem is this line:

```
this.current_node.iter_mut().for_each(...)
```

It grabs a mutable access to current_node, so it can't regain it again down the line.
Not to mention that iterating over Option is a strange decision.

If you want to move current_node to a different place, I'd try to reorganize your code such that reads are separate from writes, and they are performed in a sequence, instead of trying to do it in one go:

```
// detach the current_node for moving
if let Some(current_node_to_move) = this.current_node.take() {   
    let new_current_node_ref: &mut ... = ... // find new location logic
    new_current_node_ref.replace(current_node_to_move);
} else {
    ...
}
```

Here in line 1 it does a write None update to current_node via this, but immediately relinquishes the mutable reference. Line 2 does a read (search), but also grabs a mutable reference to a new location. Line 3 writes to this location.

To get the linked list implementation right, I recommend https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/

Comment: I rewrote everything in an _entirely_ different way, so I am no more personally interested in solving this question. My questions appears to be difficult and interesting. Can anyone write a _complete_, not partial as this solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, given your description it's hard to fill in the blank, since it is not clear what is the expected behaviour of this method. Nevertheless, I've tried to address your main points, which is: why this error happens? how to avoid this error here? how to avoid it in general? If you don't find any value in my answer, maybe it's better to close the question?

Comment: I have no "legal" right to close this question: it does not match any situation for closing. The method must more `current_node` to point to the next link in the list, without changing the list itself.

Comment: how do you define the next node in terms of the API? is DigraphNode like a linked list? so you want to find current_node in this list, find the next node, and update current to next? in this case refer to this - https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/

Comment: It is a linked list in the considered situation. So, yes, next node is the next node in the linked list.I want update current to next.

Comment: I see. I've updated the answer to refer to the linked list manual.